# How to find the frequency of each row with certain coordinate in a matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have an mx2 matrix with its rows `(0,1), (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1), (1,1), (-1,1), (1,-1),(-1,-1);` I would like to find the frequency of each of above coordinates. In other words, if I have `A=[1 1;0 1;-1 1;1 0;-1 1]`, I would like to get something like,

- number of times that `(1,1)` has appeared=1;
- number of times that `(0,1)` has appeared=1;
- number of times that `(-1,1)` has appeared=2;
- number of times that `(1,0)` has appeared=1;
- number of times that `(0,-1)` has appeared=0;
- number of times that `(-1,-1)` has appeared=0;
- number of times that `(-1,0)` has appeared=0;
- number of times that `(1,-1)` has appeared=0;

When I use `find()` command I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and then [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/histc.html):

```
[uA, ~, n] = unique(A, 'rows');
c = histc(n, 1:max(n));
```

Example: with

```
A =[ 1 1
     0 1
    -1 1
     1 0
    -1 1]
```

this gives

```
uA =
    -1     1
     0     1
     1     0
     1     1

c =
     2
     1
     1
     1
```